# Boot from USB if connected, else boot from Hard disk

Tags: grub2, live-usb, bootloader, bios, kali

I recently installed a persistent and live Kali Linux system on a USB. I want my system to boot into Kali if the USB is connected, else continue on and load GRUB (I have set up dual-boot with Ubuntu and Windows).

Can this be done? Right now every time I boot, I have to manually rearrange the BIOS boot order.

My BOOT Settings:

- Boot List Option: Legacy
- Secure Boot: Disabled
- Legacy Option ROMs: Enabled

Boot order:

```
Hard drive
USB Storage Device
Diskette Drive
Network
CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive
```

System boots into Kali if USB is connected. Else I get this error message

```
Reboot and Select proper Boot device.
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key.
```

To boot into grub, I manually change Boot List Option to UEFI. But then I'm not able to boot into Kali.

Please be as descriptive as possible as I'm a n00b to BIOS. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: reinstall kali so it is in efi mode, then set boot order so USB is before the HDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your Kali USB stick is not UEFI compatible. Make a UEFI compatible bootable USB (I personally suggest you use Rufus for this), then change your Boot Order in BIOS so that the USB is at the top, followed by your HDD. Then i should work the way you want.

Comment: If I change boot option to UEFI, I'm not able to edit boot order.

Comment: Well, that's strange. Does your BIOS have a quick boot menu? Basically, that is a quick menu that allows you to choose which device to boot. The shortcut for it changes from one model to another. May be that could help.

Comment: This worked! I had to manually add my USB as a boot option, But it works.